# Creating Illustrator top layers in SVG

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

When I load my layered SVG files into Illustrator all the layers works just as they should but they are always positioned under a new layer; "Layer 1" that I did not specify.

How do I create a SVG where my top layers end up as the top layer in Illustrator as well?

Comment: Are you creating your SVG in Illustrator?  Because, you could otherwise edit the SVG source in a text editor (it's just XML) to alter layers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create a file in Illustrator that has an organization like you want.
2. Save the SVG from Illustrator as "a.svg".
3. Re-open the SVG file in Illustrator.
   *Hey, all my layers got regrouped under Layer 1!*
4. Fix the organization.
5. Save the SVG from Illustrator with the "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities" option checked as "b.svg".
6. Re-open the SVG file in Illustrator.
   *Yay, the Layers were preserved!*
7. Diff `a.svg` and `b.svg` to see what extra metadata Illustrator is saving.
8. <strike>Mimic this data in your own file.</strike>
   Cry when you realize that the solution is an enormous proprietary blob (the `<i:pgf>` element).
9. Give up and decide it doesn't really matter all that much.

Comment: I've seen the blob-code but was hoping for a better solution. Problem is that the layers do matter a lot in my current project but I guess I will have to find another way. That "Preserve Illustrator..." extra code is not worth it.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It indeed does really matter to me so I stopped crying, spent a few hours and scripted this solution:

- Download the scripts: https://github.com/JcBernack/IllustratorScripts/archive/master.zip
- Place the "Fix SVG Layers" folder in the standard Illustrator scripts folder. Where that is depends on your installation and language, mine is at:
  C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 (64 Bit)\Presets\de_DE\Skripten
- Start Illustrator and load the SVG where all the actual layers are now groups within a new "Layer 1".
- Go to File->Scripts->Fix SVG Layers->FixSvgLayers
- Yay! All the groups are now actual layers and "Layer 1" is gone for good.

A bit more information:

- "FixSvgLayers" converts all groups within the "Layer 1" back to layers, moves them to the document root and deletes the now empty "Layer 1".
- "GroupsToLayers" converts all groups within the currently active layer to layers, without moving or deleting anything.
- Both scripts prompt for a "recursion depth" which specifies how many levels of groups-groups-groups should by converted to sub-sub-sub-layers.
- The third script (ConvertGroupsIntoLayers) is just needed by the other two, calling it from the menu opens a prompt but doesn't do anything.

When opening the SVG all the actual layers are groups within a new "Layer 1". These can be converted back without ambiguity. Sub-layers are problematic though, because there is no information to distinguish actual groups from groups which should be sub-layers (if there is please let me know!). As a workaround my script prompts for a recursion depth and converts all groups to (sub-)layers within that depth.

In my case I had three layers, where one of them was just a container for more sub-layers. To get back the original layer-structure I executed FixSvgLayers with a depth of 0, then selected the container layer and executed "GroupsToLayers" with depth of 0.

If all three layers were "container"-layers executing FixSvgLayers with a depth of 1 would have been enough to get back the correct structure.

If you don't want any groups and every group should be converted to a (sub-)layer just enter a high enough number as the recursion depth.